# Is there a way to close an open PDF file in VB.net programatically

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.net application I am opening a PDF file using
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\TEMP\MyFile.pdf").

Is it possible to Close this file Programatically in some event.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is one way, though it is not a very elegant solution.

When you start the PDF process, you capture the process-id in some global variable:

```
Dim id As Integer 'Global variable
id = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Temp\myfile.pdf").Id
```

Then, when you need to kill the process, just do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id).Kill()
```

(make sure that there is a process with this id that is actually running!)

You may also use the `Process.HasExited` property to see if the PDF has been closed, and may process your code based on that.

Comment: Rather than calling Kill, it would probably be better to call CloseMainWindow instead.  Kill forces termination, whereas CloseMainWindow will allow the process to shut down properly.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - CloseMainWindow doesn't guarantee that the PDF file will be closed which is basically the OP's requirement, though I agree that the termination will be much graceful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible to close a specific PDF file because they are not an independent process, they are sub processes in the task manager.
you can kill the adobe acrobat reader process it self.

```
Dim AcrobateInstance() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("AcroRd32")
If AcrobateInstance.Length > 0 Then
   For value As Integer = 0 To AcrobateInstance.Length - 1
      BillInstance(value).Kill()
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in C# but may come in handy...

`var myPDFEvent = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Temp\myfile.pdf");`
`myPDFEvent.Exited += new EventHandler(myPDFEvent_Exited);`
`myPDFEvent.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`

`void myPDFEvent_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)`
`{`
    `System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Temp\myfile.pdf);`
`}`

Comment: But the problem here is if the file is already open it complains that the object is in use when I try to delete it

Comment: Is that the preferred way of closing a file

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
 Process1.Start()
 Process1.WaitForExit()
 If Process1.HasExited Then
     System.IO.File.Delete(Your File Path)
 End If
```

Make sure to add the Process Object onto the form from the toolbox and configure the startinfo section.

If you are having permission problems. Use the `AppData` folder. It has the necessary permissions that programs need to run

Comment: The problem is if the pdf file is open it throws an exception saying that the file is in use, so I would want to close this file programatically and then delete it

Comment: If you are having permission problems. Use the `AppData` folder. It has the necessary permissions that programs need to run.

Comment: Its not the permission issue